# UIButton with image on left and right side using IBDesignable in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3, uibutton, autolayout, ibdesignable

How to show left and right image on left and right side with text in UIButton using IBDesignable?

I tried to google it to find any answer but did not find any smart answer. I want to do it through storyboard. Please Help

Required Output:

[image: Output Image]

Comment: You can take button image for title text set ContentInsets 
OR you can take image view on button and set constartaint

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build on this. After setting buttons in Attributes Inspector this unbutton subclass will reset the title and place images on sides (don't forget to check all edge cases):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var button: DoubleImageButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        button.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        button.layer.cornerRadius = button.bounds.height*0.5
    }
}


@IBDesignable
class DoubleImageButton: UIButton {
    /* Inspectable properties, once modified resets attributed title of the button */
    @IBInspectable var leftImg: UIImage? = nil {
        didSet {
            /* reset title */
            setAttributedTitle()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var rightImg: UIImage? = nil {
        didSet {
            /* reset title */
            setAttributedTitle()
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setAttributedTitle()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setAttributedTitle()
    }

    private func setAttributedTitle() {
        var attributedTitle = NSMutableAttributedString()

        /* Attaching first image */
        if let leftImg = leftImg {
            let leftAttachment = NSTextAttachment(data: nil, ofType: nil)
            leftAttachment.image = leftImg
            let attributedString = NSAttributedString(attachment: leftAttachment)
            let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedString)

            if let title = self.currentTitle {
                mutableAttributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: title))
            }
            attributedTitle = mutableAttributedString
        }

        /* Attaching second image */
        if let rightImg = rightImg {
            let leftAttachment = NSTextAttachment(data: nil, ofType: nil)
            leftAttachment.image = rightImg
            let attributedString = NSAttributedString(attachment: leftAttachment)
            let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedString)
            attributedTitle.append(mutableAttributedString)
        }

        /* Finally, lets have that two-imaged button! */
        self.setAttributedTitle(attributedTitle, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

In attributes inspector:
[image]

Result (adjust my implementation to achieve the best result):
[image]

Be sure to check cases when you'll have only right image selected for example but no left image etc. It's a quick solution and `not fully tested`.
Have fun and good luck! ;]

Comment: don't forget to check all edge cases??? what do you mean by this line? please explain. @Oleh

Comment: This class give me left and right image but no title.

Comment: @SourabhSharma i mean check cases when you'll have only right image selected for example but no left image etc. It's not fully tested / perfect implementation. It works with two images selected - 100%. That's what I mean :)

Comment: @SourabhSharma why not? what problems do you have? No title? how did you set the title?

Comment: @SourabhSharma how did you set the title?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138723/discussion-between-oleh-zayats-and-sourabh-sharma).

Comment: [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3HF4SLZtRvHT0lnNjBnTnhVblk/view?usp=sharing)